# How to tell travis that test is failed?

Tags: testing

I am trying to integrate travis test bots to my module. Travis can run the test correctly, in console log, I can see drush run-test discover pass and fail assertions, but the final result is still passed. Is there any trick to tell Travis know that the test is fail?

My test code is: https://travis-ci.org/andytruong/at_demo_travis/builds/12999422

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The test-run is outputting XML and reporting success on the generation, which is useful for Jenkins, but not Travis CI.

```
drush test-run --xml 'Andy Truong'
```

Change that to

```
drush test-run 'Andy Truong'
```

And you should be set.

For reference, see https://drupal.org/project/travis_ci_drupal_module_example and https://travis-ci.org/sonnym/travis-ci-drupal-module-example

Comment: I already tried without --xml in build #5 (https://travis-ci.org/andytruong/at_demo_travis/jobs/12999154). You can follow that revision.

Comment: Weird. Here's some explicit examples - https://github.com/sonnym/travis-ci-drupal-module-example/blob/master/.travis.yml#L29 also doesn't include the xml, along with http://drupalcode.org/project/opigno_poll_app.git/blob/ffc80eb4b8b15774dab13a06ae6a25f0aaa55a00:/.travis.yml - can you post your .travis.yml ?

Comment: The repos is here https://github.com/andytruong/at_demo_travis/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Test .travis.yml is correct. Issue is with drush, I changed to drupal 5.8, failed state can now be captured.

Comment: Excellent! For completeness, can you check to see if it does not detect failures if you use --xml ?

Comment: Thank you for supporting me. --xml is… useless. My issue is the version if Drush ^^

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do php scripts/run-tests.sh --all?